# Datatype conversion

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm migrating some ssrs reports from SQL Server to snowflake, in SQL Server there is money data type is using , but in snowflake money datatype is not there, so, i need to use which datatype in snowflake.
Can I use float??

Comment: Use a decimal data type for money. https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Answer (score 0):

According to MS SQL Server documentation, money is defined as:

> money -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807 - 8 Bytes

It doesn't explicitly state this, but the examples show that this is a fixed-scale number so this would be most closely represented in Snowflake as:

```
number(19,4)
```

The 19 is the precision, the maximum number of digits including the decimal portion. The 4 is the scale, the number of decimal places. Due to how Snowflake stores numbers internally, at a precision of 19 it's probably the same as specifying the max precision, which would be:

```
number(38,4)
```

If you're dealing with smaller precisions, say 12 or 10, then there could be a (slight) storage and performance benefit to reduce the scale in the defined datatype. You could also keep the precision lower to avoid bad data, such as something in the quadrillions of dollars.